# Cross browser font sizing

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

I am using a custom font via `@font-face` and I kept testing the site on **Chrome** during development.

Here's the font addition part in **CSS** for reference

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'skarpaltultra_light';
src: url('font/light-webfont.eot');
src: url('font/light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('font/light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('font/light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('font/light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('font/light-webfont.svg#skarpaltultra_light') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'skarpaltultra_light', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

***NOTE*** - The 62.5% is used because I was trying different ways of making the fonts cross-browser compatible and one of the techniques mentioned to set the font-size to this and then use `em` in the rest of the page for font sizing

Now that I opened it on **Firefox, Edge,** etc. I realized that the font sizes are all messed up and they are messing up my entire layout.

Here's a screenshot of how the site looks on **Chrome**
[image]

Here's how it looks on **Firefox**
[image]

I was about to hand over the *beta* version to the client today and then this happened. How do I fix this?

Comment: what is the <html>, <body> or root font size that you have declared?

Comment: while using percentage you remember that it is relative to the parent. remove body{font-size:62.5%;} and try.

Comment: @vssadineni -  62.5% - I've mentioned the reason in the question

Comment: @vssadineni - I have tried that already. The font sizes are still different. Like I said, I did this in an attempt to make the font sizes universal

Comment: what is the difference between firefox and chrome font-sizes?

Comment: I don't know why the font sizes are different but I included the screenshots in order to show exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font sizes are the same in both Firefox and Chrome.

Here is what it looks like in both browsers:

**As you can see both browsers compute the font size as `93.75px`.**

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

### After few adjustments:

```
h1 {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 20px double #fff;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10em;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.intro p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 5em;
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
}
table {
    bottom: 10%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image: After adjustments]

Comment: Ok, could you tell me from which element did you remove the absolute positioning?
Also, the reason I was using absolute positioning is because I wanted the text to not have parallax effect. Would making the positioning relative still allow me to do that?

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy You don't need to remove absolute positioning, just some other styling adjustments. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you tell me what adjustments you made?

Comment: I realized what was messing up the font sizes. I am using Windows 10 and Firefox adjusted to my resolution while Chrome didn't. I opened up this StackOverflow page on Chrome only to realize that when I set Chome on 125% zoom, I get the site to open in the correct resolution.
Thanks a lot for your help. I couldn't have figured it out on my own and so, I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy You are welcome. I added the code for adjustments.